# Change dataset on mousedown in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have created a bar chart from one data set. I have also created a circle object that I would like to behave as a button. On mousedown in the circle, I would like to change the data set used for the bar chart and then redraw the graph. I have tried adding the mousedown handler as a function, but the data set doesn't change when I click. Here is the original selectAll for the rectangles:

```
 svg.selectAll("rect")
         .data(data)
         .enter() 
         .append("rect")
         .attr("x", function(d, i) {
             return i * (width / data.length);})
         .attr("y", function(d) { 
             return 100 - d ;})
         .attr("width", function(d,i) {
              return barWidth ;})
         .attr("height", function(d) {
            return 150 - (100 - d);
         });
```

And here is the circle I have rendered below (which I want to be a toggle button):

```
  svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 525)
        .attr("cy", 275)
        .attr("r", 45)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("fill", "#660066")
        .attr("opacity", "0.7")
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this)
            .style("opacity", "1");
          })
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this)
            .style("opacity", "0.7");
          })
        .on("mousedown", function() {
          // handle event here
        });
```

I have tried directly copying the svg.selectAll("rect") into the mousedown function and rebinding the data to a different, predefined data set. I have also tried redefining that data set inside of the .on "mousedown" function, but the bar chart still does not redraw. Separating the mousedown into a separate function that I call outside of the svg.append("circle") does not work either. My guess is that the problem is that I'm trying to change one draw object by handling an event in another, but I feel there must be some way to solve this. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not showing us the actual code you're having a problem with. If the old and new data sets are the same size, remember that the enter selection will be empty and just copying the code will do nothing at all. You probably want to handle the update selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show your exact problem or `jsfiddle` work i may try to find the problem

The structure and flow must be like this

Two **SVG** `circle` and for `bar graph`

Two Functions

```
function drawgraph(var dataset)
{
//draw graph with this dataset
}

 function drawcircle()
{
//using `d3.js` draw circle
// and in .mousedown call the drawgraph(dataset)
}
```

Approach is simple

**seperate** the svg and also code **don't combine** both..

Comment: Thanks, it works when I put the drawgraph into a function, but how can I call the function with the initial data set when the page first loads?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Below all of my function definitions, I just had to add a function call: drawGraph();

Answer (score 0):

The code must to be something similar to this.

```
var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(data)
               .enter() 
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                  return i * (width / data.length);})
               .attr("y", function(d) { 
                  return 100 - d ;})
               .attr("width", function(d,i) {
                  return barWidth ;})
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                  return 150 - (100 - d);
            });

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 525)
    .attr("cy", 275)
    .attr("r", 45)
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("fill", "#660066")
    .attr("opacity", "0.7")
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this)
        .style("opacity", "1");
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this)
        .style("opacity", "0.7");
      })    
    .on("click", function() {
        rects.data(newdata)
             .enter() 
             .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                 return i * (width / data.length);})
             .attr("y", function(d) { 
                 return 100 - d ;})
             .attr("width", function(d,i) {
                 return barWidth ;})
             .attr("height", function(d) {
                 return 150 - (100 - d);
             });
      });
```